# Is it possible to add buy and sell tax to solana contract

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust

I want to know like how on ethereum chains you can set fee and other functions for only sell, how can that be implemented on solana

Comment: Solana has constant base fees, and a dynamic priority fees model. Do you want to know how to set priority fees?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable transfer fee for Token2022 using the transfer fee extension with `@solana/web3.js`

```
// Instruction to initialize TransferFeeConfig Extension
const initializeTransferFeeConfig =
  createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction(
    mint, // Mint Account address
    transferFeeConfigAuthority.publicKey, // Authority to update fees
    withdrawWithheldAuthority.publicKey, // Authority to withdraw fees
    feeBasisPoints, // Basis points for transfer fee calculation
    maxFee, // Maximum fee per transfer
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
 );
```

Comment: Important to note that this is a feature of the new *Token2022* standard (i.e. not *SPL*, which is what most tokens are today)

Comment: My bad thanks for catching it I edited